# Single php file to call different text files according to the url requested

Tags: php

I have a text file (articles.txt) containing 100 lines, each a body of an article:

```
<article id="1"><h1>title-here</h1> <div id="content">content-here</div></article>
<article id="2"><h1>title-here</h1> <div id="content">content-here</div></article>
...
<article id="100"><h1>title-here</h1> <div id="content">content-here</div></article>
```

Now, I want to add each of these lines into a very simple template and show them in my site using just a single file (index.php).

When **/article-2.html** is requested by a visitor, then the **inddex.php** must paste the second line of **articles.txt** into the template and show it as html codes.

I managed to do part of what I want with the following code, but it needs me to have one php file per article, which is not quite what I want.

```
echo file("articles.txt")[3];
```

So my question here is:

**Is it possible for a single php file to call different text files according to what is requested by the visitor?**

P.S. I don't want to use a database.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "[htaccess rewrite url](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/)" feature of your server to rewrite a parameter into your html file: `/article-2.html` gets treated as something like `/article.php?site=2`. Just read the "site" parameter with php `$site = $_GET['site'];` and change your output accordingly: `echo file("articles.txt")[$site];`